# Setting innerHtml property of web browser control in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on windows form in which i am using Web Browser control to load some HTML content included in  tag.

Now when I am trying to set the value of

```
       WebBrowserCntrl.Navigate("about:blank");
       HtmlDocument doc = this.WebBrowserCntrl.Document;
       doc.Write(String.Empty);
WebBrowserCntrl.Document.Body.InnerHTML= datacontractclass.datamember(string)
```

it is throwing exception as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
But when I do the other way..

`WebBrowserCntrl.DocumentText="<style>....</style>"
    WebBrowserCntrl.DocumentText= datacontractclass.datamember(string)` 
it works.
But then I am not able to change style of webbrowser.(like whatever style I have applied above)

why I am getting this exception or is there any other way to append style and other HTMl content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = string.Empty; // reset whatever is in the browser

// Either this:
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true);
doc.Write(yourHtml);
webBrowser.Refresh();

// Or:
webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true);
webBrowser.Document.Write(html);
webBrowser.Refresh();
```

You can use an `HtmlTextWriter` to create your html if you need styling inside it. For example if you would like to use an external css file, you could do this in your head section:

```
htw.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
htw.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
htw.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, pathToCssFile);
htw.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
htw.RenderEndTag();
```